# Adding sound to a custom itemsword

Tags: minecraft-forge

I am new to Minecraft modding. I want to know how to add a custom sound to a custom `ItemSword` I made, so that when any player uses the sword it makes that sound. I am using Forge for Minecraft 1.8.

I have read different tutorials, but all are to do with custom entities. Could someone show me an example with a `ItemSword` class.

Comment: Hmm. Pulling up the code I have for playing music is rather complex and at the end, plays a record (like the jukebox) rather than a sound effect (the last method invoked is different). That said, playing a sound from an item isn't any different than from an entity: the only thing to note is that you need the player's client to inform the server, so that the server can inform everyone nearby that the sound needs to be played.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented this in 1.11.2 so I would guess that is mostly the same in 1.8

Have a look at my github: [MoaiBlock Sound](https://github.com/nlxdodge/ScrapYard/blob/master/src/main/java/com/nlxdodge/scrapyard/Blocks/MoaiBlock.java)

Here is the line of code I have used:

```java
playerIn.playSound(new SoundEvent(new ResourceLocation(Controller.MODID, "moai_interact")), 1.0f, 1.2f);
```

you should play the sound at the player which uses the item/block make a new *SoundEvent* and give a *ResourceLocation* and set loudness and pitch of the audio.

I suggest that you look at Github for 1.8 projects where people implemented sound already and learn from there. That is what I have done to.